# Создание ехе файла с java проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, exe

Есть готовый десктопный проект на Java, с GUI интерфейсом. Проект был разработан в среде Intellij Idea. Но при разработке я не выбрал JavaFx,а просто Java Application. Как создать ехe? Пробовал сделать jar file и через launch4j сделать ехе. Не получилось. Возможно кто имеет какие-то идеи ?

Comment: "Пробовал сделать jar file и через launch4j сделать ехе. Не получилось" - это не повод задавать обкатанный вопрос. Задавайте вопрос о том, почему не получается, прикладывая всю необходимую информацию (погуглив естественно проблему, прежде чем задавать вопрос),

Comment: @Vitaliy На каком фреймфорке написан GUI? Swing? JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите AOT виртуальные ява машины, например [Excelsior Jet](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/)